# How to split the day of week to many columns with converting to zeros and ones

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If I have a data frame like that:

Sales         Day_Of_Week

1290           Monday

5432          Tuesday

67543         Friday

2121          Monday

31322        Saturday

2323          Sunday

7895          Monday

4342          Friday

11238        Saturday

How to split "Day_Of_Week" to many columns to be the data frame like that:

df = Sales  Day_Of_Week     Monday  Tuesday     Friday  Saturday    Sunday

```
  1290    Monday           1       0           0        0         0

  5432   Tuesday           0       1           0        0         0

  67543  Friday            0       0           1        0         0

   2121  Monday            1       0           0        0         0

  31322 Saturday           0       0           0        1         0

  2323  Sunday             0       0           0        0         1

  7895  Monday             1       0           0        0         0

  4342  Friday             0       0           1        0         0

  1238  Saturday           0       0           0        1         0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

df = '1        0        0         0           0  '.split()

c=0
for i in df:
    c+=1
    i = int(i)
    if(i==1 and c==1):
        print("Monday")
    if(i==1 and c==2):
        print("Tuesday")
    if(i==1 and c==3):
        print("Friday")
    if(i==1 and c==4):
        print("Saturday")        
    if(i==1 and c==5):
        print("Sunday")  
>>Monday
```

or in other direction:

```
df = "Monday"
output = np.zeros(5)
if(df == "Monday"):
    output[0] = 1

print(output)
>>[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The "Day_of_week" is one of the columns in the dataframe. I want to split this column to many other columns where the name of this columns will be "Saturday", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday" and "Friday" with converting to zeros and ones.

Comment: can write a short example in your quesion

Comment: This is a simple example:

Comment: Sales Day_Of_Week  Monday  Tuesday  Friday  Saturday  Sunday 
1290 Monday   1 0 0 0 0
5432 Tuesday  0 1 0 0 0
67543 Friday  0 0 1 0 0
2121 Monday  1 0 0 0 0
31322 Saturday  0 0 0 1 0
2323 Sunday  0 0 0 0 1
7895 Monday  1 0 0 0 0
4342 Friday  0 0 1 0 0
11238 Saturday  0 0 0 1 0

Comment: I will make changing in my question, this will make it easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

dow = []
dow.append("1290 Monday")
dow.append("5432 Tuesday")
dow.append("67543 Friday")
dow.append("2121 Monday")
dow.append("31322 Saturday")
dow.append("2323 Sunday")
dow.append("7895 Monday")
dow.append("4342 Friday")
dow.append("11238 Saturday")

# Monday Tuesday Friday Saturday Sunday
output = [0] * 7
for entry in dow:
    print(entry)
    output = [0] * 7
    first_split = entry.split()

    if(first_split[1] == "Monday"):
        output[0] = first_split[0]
        output[1] = str("Monday")
        output[2] = 1

    if(first_split[1] == "Tuesday"):
        output[0] = first_split[0]
        output[1] = str("Tuesday")
        output[3] = 1        

    if(first_split[1] == "Friday"):
        output[0] = first_split[0]
        output[1] = str("Friday")
        output[4] = 1        

    if(first_split[1] == "Saturday"):
        output[0] = first_split[0]
        output[1] = str("Saturday")
        output[5] = 1                

    if(first_split[1] == "Sunday"):
        output[0] = first_split[0]
        output[1] = str("Sunday")
        output[6] = 1        

    print(output)
```

the output is:

```
1290 Monday
['1290', 'Monday', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5432 Tuesday
['5432', 'Tuesday', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
67543 Friday
['67543', 'Friday', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
2121 Monday
['2121', 'Monday', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
31322 Saturday
['31322', 'Saturday', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
2323 Sunday
['2323', 'Sunday', 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
7895 Monday
['7895', 'Monday', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4342 Friday
['4342', 'Friday', 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
11238 Saturday
['11238', 'Saturday', 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Steven. The dataframe which I have has 87 rows, it is hard for me to repeat "dow.append" 87 times... Is there any way for doing that in an easier way

Comment: you have them in a file?

Comment: I have an csv filew here the "Day_Of_Week" is one of the independent variables. I used "Pandas" to put the content of the CSV file in a dataframe. I want now to split the "Day_Of_Week" to many other columns where the header of each column is the day name: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday. Friday, Saturday and Wednesday.

Comment: I have to do make a preparation of the data before using the machine learning algorithm for classification.

Comment: okay, but how is your data given? as a textfile? as query of a database? a webinterface...?

Comment: The data is given as a CSV file. I don't know the source of this data, but all what I need to do is working on this CSV file and building predictive model based on this data.